# Facebook messenger unread issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebookatwork

I'm facing problem when working with Facebook API.

I try sending messages from my java service to my FB account by "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/me/messages" API.

Then I open and read the message. After that I reload page, but FB still show the conversation is unread. The problem still occurs even when I click "Mark as read" button.
Other conversations works normally except conversation with my BOT.

My post body like this:

```
{
  recipient: {id: $user_id},
  message: {text: $content}
}
```

Can anyone help me how to mark this conversation as read? Is it FB system issue, or caused by Graph API?